# Call of regedit and copies silently fail on Vista/7 with admin privileges?

Tags: c#, registry, administrator

I am trying to set support information on machines with C#. I have one registry file to import (I have tried with Microsoft.Win32 as well, code below has process call commented) and two files to copy into system32. The files are on a share and other portions of the code interact properly with share. First code so I might be way off here

```
try
                {
                    //String pathtooemreg = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%HOMEDRIVE%\Windows\System32\oeminfo.reg");
                    //System.IO.File.Copy(@"\\files\tools\oeminfo.reg", (pathtooemreg), true);
                    //Process p = new Process();
                    //p.StartInfo.FileName = @"regedit";
                    //p.StartInfo.Arguments = " /s" + (pathtooemreg);
                    //p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                    //p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    //p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    //p.Start();
                    //p.WaitForExit();
                    Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\OEMInformation", "Model", "");
                    Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\OEMInformation", "Manufacturer", "somecompanyname");
                    Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\OEMInformation", "Logo", "oemlogo.bmp");
                    Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\OEMInformation", "SupportPhone", "somephonenumber");
                    Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\OEMInformation", "SupportURL", "someurl");
                    Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\OEMInformation", "SupportHours", "");
                    String pathtooeminfo = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%HOMEDRIVE%\Windows\System32\oeminfo.ini");             
                    System.IO.File.Copy(@"\\files\tools\oeminfo.ini", (pathtooeminfo), true);
                    String pathtooemlogo = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%HOMEDRIVE%\Windows\System32\oemlogo.bmp");
                    System.IO.File.Copy(@"\\files\tools\oemlogo.bmp", (pathtooemlogo), true);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(@"3b.Done Installing OEM/Support info.");
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(this, "Error: " + err.Message);
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invariably questions such as these arise due to you running a 32 bit process and registry redirection meaning that the settings are made in the 32 bit registry view. Silent failure is probably actually success, but the settings are not being made where you expect.

I expect you'll find your settings under HKLM\Software.Wow6432Node. Write to the 64 bit view either by targetting AnyCPU or by using the RegistryView enumeration.

The code that copies files will fall foul of the file system redirector in much the same way.